# Firebase not initialized for some reason

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Error:
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown building Builder:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp

I installed everything for firebase all of the dependencies, and made sure my build.gradle was straight. But for some reason this problem keeps persisting, I searched everywhere and this is my current code, any help is appreciated.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'frontend/web/mobile/login.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Samaritan',
          theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
          home: login(),
        );
      }
    
  }
```

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.3
  http: ^0.13.0
```

I've tried different ways to initialize it from the internet including creating another function that initializes it, but notthing works.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization process did not complete so you encounter that error, you should add `async` signature to the  `main` function and add `await` keyword before `Firebase.initializeApp();` like the example in the document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i keep getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: in that case, I think you missed the `google-services.json` inside yourapp/android/app or `GoogleService-Info.plist` inside yourapp/ios/Runner. I suggest using [flutterfire cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios) to make the firebase installation easier